# remove facial recognition for deleted user

Tags: windows-11, windows-hello

Windows version: Win 11, 22H2
Firstly, I have a user, named "user01", I've setup facial here,
Then, I removed the `user01` and create my current user,
Now when I try to setup Facial on this user, Windows throw error message and I can't remove the old facial.
and in Control Panel/User Account, my old account has been removed so I can't connect there to remove the facial

So, How could I remove the facial recognition for a deleted account?

```
Sorry, something went wrong
It looks like you've already set up Windows Hello on another account. Remove face recognition from
your other account, and then try again.
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my bad searching skill,
After some minutes jumping around over internet, I found [the answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/remove-old-fingerprintface-from-deleted-account/6c377f24-ba0b-4628-8268-6a53ae4ed8fa)

> 1. Click Start. Type Services and select it from the list of results.
> 2. Right-click the Windows Biometrics Service from the list and click Stop.
> 3. Open File Explorer. Navigate to this location: C:\Windows\System32\WinBioDatabase.
> 4. Delete all the .DAT files in the folder. If you can't see anything in the folder, click the View tab in File Explorer and check Hidden Items.
> 5. After deleting the .DAT  files, try setting up Windows Hello again.

Comment: Answers which cite an external source must also make it clear what they have quoted from that source.